# How to restrict a user in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I create a signup page, after sign up, user go to a page that is "Complete your profile".

When user complete the profile data will be stored in data base.

I want that if user completed the profile, than they cannot again entered data into a page.
If user again try to enter the data,  page will not allowed to that user to again enter data,
and show message to user "You have already completed your profile".

How can I restrict the user?

Anyone tell me how?

Comment: For that you have to make some field Mandatory like email, username,or dob and while submitting check whether emailid already exists in your Database table if yes then show alert already exists.

Comment: what is your development environment? MVC5 or new .NetCore?

Comment: Manish Goswami: i know....!                       But how i can?   tell me procedure

Comment: Mike Anderson: Asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You can check what you want to decide that a profile is complete or none in a method.(e.g `IsProfileCompleted(string userId);`) and call this method inside your profile entry action.

```
  ProfileEntryAction()
    {
    if(IsProfileCompleted(string userId))
    return View("ProfileCompleted");
    return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user navigates to the Profile page, before actually showing the Profile page, check (server side) whether there already *is* a profile. If there is (according to your specs), redirect the user to an "already completed" message. If there is no profile, continue and show the profile page.

Check whether a profile exists by testing for example:

- does the profile record exist?
- does the profile contain enough data (required fields have been filled in)?
- or some other test that is specific to your system

Comment: Hans Kesting : can you give me example in case of code?

Comment: @BilawalNiaz - I'm not exactly sure what you mean. You will probably need to use a query against your database to find out whether the record exists or has enough data.

Comment: sir i know but i restrict user on web on asp.net not data base

Comment: @BilawalNiaz - you restrict access to the page *based on* what is stored in the database. I updated the wording in the answer.

Comment: i want to restrict the user through username